# Bind and Unbind Events in Jquery

Tags: jquery-mobile

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function(event) {
            $("#mybtn").on("click", function(e) {
                $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
                $.mobile.changePage("twitter.html", {
                    reloadPage: false, changeHash: true,
                });
                $('#mybtn').unbind('');

            });
        });
```

Can u tell me why Unbind is important in Jquery mobile and Please tell me best way To unbind events.I used Following way to bind and unbind events.Is that ok

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example: [**NO UNBIND USED**](http://jsfiddle.net/PvE4Q/)

**CODE**

```
$("#page2").on("pagebeforeshow", function(){
    $("#testBtn").on("click", function(){
       alert("Hi!"); 
    });
});
```

If you go from page 1 to page 2, and then click the button named `Click me` you will see that the alert "Hi!" is shown properly. The event was binded on `pagebeforeshow`, till now everything is ok.

Now go back to page1, and then load again page2, click again the `Click me` button.. you will see that the alert is shown 2 times! and this is WRONG. That's why you need to `unbind` the event BEFORE you bind it again.

Basically, every time you load page2, you bind a new event to the button.. so, if you load 10 times that page, you will have 10 events binded to the button, that will fire once the button is clicked.

Here's a working fiddle with the `unbind` (to unbind the event, I used `off()`): [**UNBIND USED**](http://jsfiddle.net/3BxHp/1/)

**CODE**

```
$("#page2").on("pagebeforeshow", function(){
    $("#testBtn").off("click").on("click", function(){
       alert("Hi!"); 
    });
});
```

have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to understand why I used `off()` instead of `unbind()`, and also [here](http://api.jquery.com/off/) if you wat to see how `off()` works

I hope this helps to clarify your doubts..

Comment: $(document).on('click.register', '.registerSubmitter', function(e) {
    // do something
});  
what do you think about this method
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950443/how-to-properly-unbind-events-in-jquery-mobile-using-on-off-when-a-page-is-kept